# Swift + GIDSignIn - hasAuthInKeyChain returns true but currentUser is still nil after calling signInSilently

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, keychain, google-signin

I'm attempting to integrate Google sign-in into my app. Right now, I'm able to successfully log in a user with a Google account and the app works as expected - I'm able to access `currentUser`, get some information from it, and fill my app's views with the information. The problem is that when I relaunch the app, I'm unable to get a `GIDGoogleUser` even after calling `signInSilently`. `hasAuthInKeychain` returns true, so I know that an auth token must exist in the keychain. I just can't figure out why `currentUser` still returns nil after signing a user back into the app. The code I've written is below:

```
    guard let signIn = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance() else { fatalError() }
    signIn.scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.read", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"]
    signIn.clientID = FIRApp.defaultApp()?.options.clientID
    signIn.delegate = self
    if signIn.hasAuthInKeychain() {
        signIn.signInSilently()
    }

    if signIn.hasAuthInKeychain() || FBSDKAccessToken.current() != nil {

        var token = String()
        if let user = signIn.currentUser{
            token = user.userID
        } else{
            token = FBSDKAccessToken.current().userID
        }
    }
```

The app tries to sign in silently since `hasAuthInKeychain` returns true. But it skips past the `if let` statement because `currentUser` is nil and goes directly into trying to find a `FBSDKAccessToken`. I've tried all the suggestions I've found including setting the sign-in scopes. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. First I thought it was a timing issue. By invoking signIn.signInSilently() **after** fully loading the root viewController it did work. I am now 99% sure I solved it by executing signIn.signInSilently() on the main thread through:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    gidSignIn.signInSilently()
}
```

Comment: So I actually figured out what the issue was for me. I was calling `signInSilently` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and then trying to retrieve `currentUser` directly after that. `currentUser` only becomes populated in the delegate method (`didSignInForUser`) so I needed to retrieve the user there.